# Nodemon crashes simple html

Tags: javascript, html, nodemon

Hi can't get a simple index.html page to work with nodemon.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    hello ya all
  </body>
</html>
```

The versions are as follows,

```
^Cshane@XPS:~/peripheralvisionchecker$ npm -v
8.19.2
shane@XPS:~/peripheralvisionchecker$ node -v
v18.9.0
shane@XPS:~/peripheralvisionchecker$ nodemon -v
2.0.20
```

Trying to run the simple file index.html with nodemon gives,

```
shane@XPS:~/peripheralvisionchecker$ nodemon index.html 
[nodemon] 2.0.20
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: html,json
[nodemon] starting `node index.html`
/home/shane/peripheralvisionchecker/index.html:1
<!DOCTYPE html>
^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:360:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1048:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1083:27)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1173:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:997:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:838:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:18:47

Node.js v18.9.0
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Why does nodemon keep crashing?

Comment: nodeman is a Javascript runner. You're trying trying to execute an HTML file as Javascript. It sounds like you're completely guessing at what you're doing, without reading documentation or searching first. What are you trying to accomplish? I would probably close this question and Google for what you're trying to do, and read a tutorial.

Comment: I'm trying to run nodemon index.html http-server is working but unfortunately that does update changes saved to the file.

Comment: Please re-read my comment, and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking additional questions. You don't know what nodemon does, that's not what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You need server-side or node module,
You can't just run html files by nodemon, Nodemon is live javascript runner.

Information about How does server side works & Choose backend framework or module as you like to call, Like:

`Express JS, Koa, Fastify, Nest, Ember JS, BackboneJS, Vue JS, Knockout JS, Angular, Meteor, Sails JS` and more

You can check documentation for each by just searching "`(Express Documentation  e.g.)`" to get more information about the server side that you want to use, I recommend you to use ExpressJS, As far as projects that i did with expressjs it's amazing.

---

I would like also to take a look on

[Server-side website programming](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side)

[Express/Node introduction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs/Introduction)

[Introduction to the server side](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/First_steps/Introduction)

Answer (score -3):

It looks like you are just editing a static HTML file.  Once you save the file just refresh your browser and you should see your changes.

Comment: Please don't post comments as answers. The error message in the question is not related to your comment.

Comment: it was an answer..

Comment: Ok so I have to have framework such as express working. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Congrats dude. Keep at it